# Folder writeable by "others" in a linux server

Tags: php, apache, security

I need to have a folder where `php` can write. As far as I know `php` is "others" in a unix system and so I had to do:

```
chmod o=rwx /path/to/writeable/dir
```

My question is: can a folder like that represent a security problem for the system?

Comment: php can write or apache can write?  and who upvoted a question like this ?

Comment: yeah php module for apache can write, that's what I meant. Sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending of the user of apache (usually `www-data` or `apache2`) I would give the folder to apache :

```
chown apache2 myFolder -Rf
```